# Ocultar hoja con Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Leo un excel con:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\miPlantilla.xlsx"));

XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
XSSFSheet sheet;
if(condicion) {
    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
} else {
    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);//<-Uso otra hoja
}
XSSFRow row;
XSSFCell cell;

//Modifico datos.
```

Ahora lo que intento para ocultar una de las dos hojas:

```
if(condicion) {
    workbook.setSheetHidden(0, true);
} else {
    workbook.setSheetHidden(1, true);
}
```

Pero me lanza la excepción:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sheet index (2) is out of range (0..1)

¿Alguien sabe qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: te sugiero usar setSheetHidden: "https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html"

Comment: ¿Seguro que ese es todo el código relevante? En alguna parte estás enviando un índice 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final me faltaba activar la otra hoja para que oculte la hoja.

```
if(condicion) {
    workbook.setActiveSheet(1);
    workbook.setSheetHidden(0, true);
} else {
    workbook.setActiveSheet(0);
    workbook.setSheetHidden(1, true);
}
```